# public list errors

Tags: apex

I have a custom lead convert page that I am trying to add Lead Status Reason field to under Lead Status:

```
   <!-- Converted Status -->
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Converted Status" for="leadStatus" />
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput" layout="block">
            <div class="requiredBlock"></div>
            <apex:selectList id="LeadStatusList" size="1" 
                value="{!LeadToConvert.Status}" multiselect="false" required="true">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!LeadStatusOption}"/>
            </apex:selectList> 
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
            <apex:outputLabel value="Converted Status Reason" for="leadStatusReason" />
            <apex:outputPanel styleClass="Input" layout="block">
                <div class="Block"></div>
                <apex:selectList id="LeadStatusReasonList" size="1" 
                value="{!LeadToConvert.Lead_Status_Reason__c}" multiselect="false" required="false">
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:outputPanel>               
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

I added the field to my page, but I cannot get the picklist values to appear in the drop down on the page.

When attempting to mimic the public class apex code for Lead Status so that I can call the values, it doesn't work. This is what I was attempting to mimic:

```
// set up the Lead Status pick list
public List<SelectOption> LeadStatusOption {

    get {           

        if(LeadStatusOption == null) {

            LeadStatusOption = new List<SelectOption>();

            //get the lead statuses
            LeadStatus [] ls = [select MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true order by SortOrder];

            // if there is more than 1 lead status option, add a NONE option  
            if (ls.size() > 1) {
                LeadStatusOption.add(new SelectOption('NONE', '-None'));
            }

            // add the rest of the lead status options
            for (LeadStatus convertStatus : ls){
                LeadStatusOption.add(new SelectOption(convertStatus.MasterLabel, convertStatus.MasterLabel));
            } 

        }

        return LeadStatusOption;
    }
    set;
}
```

I have searched other apex classes to see if the lists are being called elsewhere or if I could better understand why I cannot successfully call the picklist values onto my page without any luck. Hope this edit helps convey my issue more clearly. TIA.

Comment: Define "not working"? What errors do you have? Please be detailed when you post questions so we can best assist you.

Comment: It's not finding the list, which I imagine is because where am I calling the values of my field? I don't see it. "Unexpected Token 'List'" is the error. Also, I get "Invalid type: LeadStatusOption". And "Variable does not exist: Lead_Status_Reason__c".

Comment: The errors don't match this code. You're going to need to post more code so we can help you. Please [edit] your question with additional code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Lead_Status_Reason__c` is a picklist field, why don't you just use `<apex:inputField>` ?  This tag automatically detects single and multi-select picklist fields, date fields, etc.  It's a lot easier to deal with.

If you must use `<apex:selectList>` for some reason, then you need to specify an `<apex:selectOptions>` tag in order to display the picklist values.  The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm) has a pretty clear example for a multi-select picklist:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!countries}" multiselect="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
</apex:selectList><p/>
```

Comment: I believe this worked as I no longer have errors, but when I go into the platform to look at the page, it says "The dependent picklist 'Lead Status Reason' requires its controlling field 'Lead Status' to be present on the page." This doesn't make sense because Lead Status is and always has been on the page. I am just adding Lead Status Reason. Do I need to call out anything specific now that the dependent field is on there?